# Sharepoint Search - Managed property name contain hyphen "-" not working

Tags: search, query-string

I created one custom managed property name SolutionName-Description and doing the full crawl after that.

The issue is it returns no result when I query by this managed property: SolutionName-Description:Test*

But when I remove the hyphen, it works. sharepoint does not allow "_" but the "-" is accepted in managed property name. any idea???

Comment: This might give you an idea what characters you can use and what are reserved in SharePoint. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks like this:

**"My-Property"**:value

Keep in mind that if you're doing this, for example, in javascript code and construct a query with multiple parameters then you might also need to escape those quotation marks:

var searchQuery = String.format("{0}/_api/search/query?" +
"querytext='(ContentTypeId:0x010100* AND **\"additionalQueryText\"**)'&"+
                "selectproperties='ListItemID,Title,ModifiedOWSDATE'&rowlimit={1}&startrow={2}",    _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, 
pageSize,currentPage * pageSize );

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any special characters. In my experience it always appears that the query parser is breaking the query at the hyphen. It also negates the query term (using `-term` will remove results with that term).